# pass variable into javascript object

Tags: javascript

Can you please help with my problem

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
var data = {                                   

    'rows[0][name]':    'foshka',
    'rows[0][tel]':    '096',
    'rows[0][opt]':    'none'

};
```

The problem is that i get an error while trying to pass variable as rows index:

```
var i = 0;
var data = {                                   

    'rows['+ i +'][name]':   'one',
    'rows['+ i +'][tel]':    '096',
    'rows['+ i +'][opt]':    'none'

};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are the property names all strings?

Comment: It is legal syntax, though I have a feeling he is not doing what he thinks he is doing.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it actually an error, or is data not turning out like you expected?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/javascript-jquery-using-a-variable-in-the-css-property-of-animate/2274327#2274327

Answer (score 4):

Your code has to be

```
var data = {};
data[ 'rows['+ i +'][name]' ] = 'one';
data[ 'rows['+ i +'][tel]' ] = '069';
```

However you might want to change your structure to sth like this:

```
var data ={};
var i = 0;
data['rows'][i]['name'] = 'one';
```

Or even cleaner:

```
var data = { rows[] };

var i = 0;
data['rows'][i] = { 'name' : 'one', 'tel' : 069' };

// so you can access them like this:
alert ( data['rows'][i]['name'] );
```

Comment: The second structure will throw an error unless `data['rows']` and `data['rows'][i]` are defined first.

Comment: Please change it into option two - currently it's a crime against programming :)

Comment: There's no requirement to use bracket notation to define crazy object properties. Only when accessing said properties is it necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think your data should look like this:

```
var data = {
  rows: [{
    name: 'one',
    tel: '096',
    opt: null
  }]
};
```

That way you can simply add new rows if needed.