# How do I interpolate a variable as a key in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How can I use the value of the variable `a` as a key to lookup a property? I want to be able to say: `b["whatever"]` and have this return 20:

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = {a : 20};     // Want this to assign b.whatever
alert(b["whatever"]); // so that this shows 20, not `undefined`
```

I am asking if it's possible during the creation of `b`, to have it contain `"whatever":20` instead of `a:20` where "whatever" is itself in a variable. Maybe an `eval` could be used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a dynamic key to be added to a javascript object variable.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-to-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable) and [pass variable into javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309221/pass-variable-into-javascript-object) and probably others...

Comment: I'm guessing when you say "interpolate," you mean "use." Just so it doesn't cause you problems in the future, interpolate means "estimate unknown values between known values" and doesn't fit in this question title at all.

Comment: No, he's using correct terminology. You're referring to interpolation in the field of mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation He's referring to interpolation in the field of computer science. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation. :-)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript asks the same thing but formulated in a different way, neither of them in a particularly _wrong_ way.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = {};
b[a] = 20;
alert(b["whatever"]); // shows 20
```

Comment: Disagree that this is a poor answer on the merit of the code and answering the OP's question. Agree that it could be better by adding some supporting text to explain why what the OP wants to do doesn't simply work in JS and some reasoning behind the answer's operation. Supporting citations would also be a welcome addition. But this is a solid solution pre-ES6.

Answer (score 61):

This works in Firefox 39 and Chrome 44. Don't know about other browsers. Also it doesn't work in nodejs v0.12.7.

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = { [a]: 20 };
console.log(b["whatever"]); // shows 20
```

That is, to interpolate a variable, enclose it in brackets.

I'm not sure if this is a part of any standard. Originally, I saw such syntax here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-classes/ where the author defined:

```
[functionThatReturnsPropertyName()] (args) { ... }
```

I'm also not sure if you should use that syntax. It's not widely known. Other members on your team might not understand the code.

Comment: Javascript syntax support is more important that just code readability. It matters that the user's browser doesn't fail! The syntax is part of the upcoming ECMAScript 6, and it's only supported in very recent browsers: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions

Comment: v4.2.6 also supports it

Comment: Totally the right answer for those who can use ES6, shame some browsers do not yet even in 2018. This solution is better than the accepted answer here as it provides more legible and concise code.

Comment: This is a great answer, because it allows you to construct the object in one statement, which plays nicely with one-line arrow functions with parentheses

Comment: This should be safe to use at this point in time unless you're looking to support IE.

Answer (score 6):

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = {a : 20};
b[a] = 37;
alert(b["whatever"]); // 37
```

`'a'` is a string with the value `'a'`. `a` is a variable with the value `'whatever'`.

Answer (score 5):

Great question. I had a time trying to figure this out with underscore but the answer couldn't be more simple:

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = {a : 20};

var array = [a, b]
var answer = _.object([[array]])// {whatever: {a:20}}//NOTICE THE DOUBLE SET OF BRACKETS AROUND [[array]]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Care to explain why this works, please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var a = "whatever";
var c = "something";
var b = {whatever : 20, something: 37};
alert(b[a]); // Shows 20
alert(b[c]); // Shows 37
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JxrB8/).

Or if I understand from the below comments correctly, try this:

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = {a : 20};
alert(b.a); // Shows 20
```

Comment: But there's no way to directly initialise it? We have to do it like this?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there is a way to make it "dereference" it somehow and not consider it a string. Why is this the default behaviour in js?

Comment: @Geo i believe that might be another question you might want to ask, im not sure

Comment: @Felix -- @Rocket also seems about the same answer

Comment: Isn't the key interpreted as string so you really can't use it like that?

Comment: The update is wrong, `b.a` is parsed as `b['a']` not `b['whatever']`

Comment: @bendman: I agree with you. Also `{ a: 20 }` is interpreted as `{'a':20}`, not as `{'whatever' : 20}`.

Answer (score 0):

To show all options, I want mention the [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) way of doing this, which is:

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = (
  obj = {},
  obj["" + a] = 20,
  obj
);

alert(b.whatever); // 20
```

Although I prefer:

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = {};
b[a] = 20;

alert(b.whatever); // 20
```