# javascript object variable key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a plugin for Jquery and need to have a variable as a key in an object.

```
$(selector).animate({self.settings.direction: '+='+self.displacement+'px'}, "slow" , function () {});
```

this part causes the error:

> self.settings.direction

any ideas where my syntax is wrong?
thank you

Comment: I think the following link shows a pretty good solution I came up with for this using underscore.  It couldn't be easier! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640988/how-do-i-interpolate-a-variable-as-a-key-in-a-javascript-object/30608422#30608422

Answer (score 85, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. Whatever is in front of the colon in the object literal notation will be automatically interpreted as a string. You will need to construct your object beforehand, and use the square bracket notation.

```
var options = {}
options[self.settings.direction] = '+=' + self.displacement + 'px';
$(selector).animate(options, "slow" , function () {});
```

EDIT: You can now:

```
const prop = "foo"
const bad = { prop: "bar" } // { prop: "bar" }
const good = { [prop]: "bar" } // { foo: "bar" }
```

so...

```
$(selector).animate({ [self.settings.direction]: '+='+self.displacement+'px'}, "slow" , function () {});
```

Comment: Easy to forget that's available

Answer (score 11):

If the value is also a string you could use JSON.parse:

```
var a = 'key';
var b = 'value';
var test = JSON.parse('{"' + a + '":"' + b + '"}"');
//test = {key: 'value'}
```

Comment: +1: equal parts ugly and useful. Very handy.

Comment: What is this dark magic!? They should include this method in Coffeescript to add variable key superpowers.

Comment: might be a good idea to escape double quotes like: ```JSON.parse('{\"' + a + '\":\"' + b + '\"}')```

Answer (score 7):

You can access the string defined by a variable with toString().
so :

```
var obj = new Object;

obj.a = 0;
obj.b = 1;

var a = "b";

obj["a"]; // will output 0
obj[a.toString()] // will output 1
```

Comment: The `.toString()` call is unnecessary. The variable `a` is already a string. All you need to do is remove the quotes: http://jsfiddle.net/FJCFW/.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you are defining an object there between the curly brackets. You can't use dots in property names. Assuming the displacement property is set somewhere else earlier, this will work for you:

```
$(selector).animate({settings: {direction: '+='+self.displacement+'px'}}, "slow" , function () {})
```