# Key as a variable for backbone.js model.set()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Referring to the [model.set()](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) function in backbone.js: Is there a way to supply the key value as a variable rather than having it hard-coded?

In my code below, setting the key as the variable *prop* literally sets the name of the key as "prop" whereas I need the name of the key to actually be the value stored in the variable *prop*.

```
var filters = new Filters();

for (var pair in facetsCollection) {
    for (var prop in facetsCollection[pair]) {
        filters.set({prop: (facetsCollection[pair])[prop]);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript object variable key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071471/javascript-object-variable-key)

Comment: It doesn't matter what lib you're using, JavaScript is JavaScript. Set the attribute using square bracket notation.

Comment: I looked at the thread you referenced but their implementation seems to be slightly different from what I am trying to achieve. The variable prop has a string value, which needs to be the name of the key. The method follows the format: filters.set({key: value});

Comment: actually it's the same, if you think of it as, the options the other guy wants to pass to the CSS in jquery, is also with a specific variable key, could be  width, could be height, etc etc... and then a value. you can see in my post below how you create such a hash with key value pairs, and then you just pass it into the function, for you it's the model.set() function, for the other guy in the referenced thread it's the jquery.animate() function.

Comment: @kaspnord, the problem and solution is exactly the same as what you accepted...

Comment: Sorry, I am new to javascript and was a little confused at what I was looking at. I do see now that the post you referenced is in line with the solution I am seeking - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it easily like this:

```
var filters = new Filters();

// building of an options hash
var options = {}
for (var pair in facetsCollection) {
    for (var prop in facetsCollection[pair]) {
        options[prop] = (facetsCollection[pair])[prop];
    }
}

// setting the options all at once instead of 1 at a time in the for loops
filters.set(options);
```