# jQuery extend with key in variable

Tags: jquery, extend

I have this function to add key in a data with k="Toto"

```
 $Root = $("#" + n); $Root.data("TFO", $.extend({ k: v }, $Root.data("TFO")));
```

But when I see `$Root.data("TFO")` I get `k` instead of the value in `k`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var obj = {};
 obj[ k ] = v; //<--------- VALUE of k will be used here & NOT k
 $Root = $("#" + n); 
 $Root.data("tfo", $.extend(obj, $Root.data("tfo")));
 //or $Root.data()['tfo'] = $.extend( obj, $Root.data('tfo') );
```

Comment: It's exactly what I say in my last post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no matter what is the case in your `data-TFO` attribute you have to access it in lower case: `$Root.data("tfo")`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/x39az4r4/)

Comment: my probleme is not tfo Or TFO. But k. In final I've $Root.data("TFO")[k] instead of $Root.data("TFO")[Toto"]

Comment: Sorry then I still didn't get your problem. You defined your data to have the key of 'k' and the value of 'Toto' so accessing ```$Root.data("TFO")['k']``` is the only correct way to get 'Toto' and you can't do ```$Root.data("TFO")['Toto']``` since 'Toto' is not a key.

Comment: k is a variable from function(n,k,v){...} k is not the real name but inside (Toto) is the name I Want

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I change my resarch on google and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071471/javascript-object-variable-key) 
then result

```
function AddK($r, k, v) { var options = {}; options[k] = v; $r.data("TFO", $.extend(options, $r.data("TFO"))); }
```