# How to add objects dynamically in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to generate the variable and assign inside for loop dynamically?

For Example,,

```
var tempClosingBalance, k = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < customArray.length; i++) {
    tempClosingBalance = "ClosingBalanceWithType" + k;
    for (var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
        output[j].tempClosingBalance = customArray[i][j].ClosingBalanceWithType;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Here `tempClosingBalance` variable have `ClosingBalanceWithType1` and assign value, Same condition continued assign value in `ClosingBalanceWithType2`, `ClosingBalanceWithType3`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript object variable key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071471/javascript-object-variable-key)

Comment: this has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work. The direct `.` operator will not work here.

Use `output[j]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + k]`.

```
var tempClosingBalance, k = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < customArray.length; i++) {
    tempClosingBalance = "ClosingBalanceWithType" + k;
    for (var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
        output[j][tempClosingBalance] = customArray[i][j].ClosingBalanceWithType;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < customArray.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
                output[j]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + k] = customArray[i][j].ClosingBalanceWithType;
                output[j]["TransactionCount" + k] = customArray[i][j].TransactionCount ? customArray[i][j].TransactionCount : 0;
                output[j]["AmountType" + k] = customArray[i][j].AmountType;
            }
            k++;
        }
```