# AngularJS: ng-model inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to generate form inputs with ng-repeat.
Note: 'customFields' is an array of field names: ["Age", "Weight", "Ethnicity"].

```
 <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="field in customFields">
   <label class="control-label">{{field}}</label>
     <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" ng-model="person.customfields.{{field}}" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

What is the best/correct way to set 'ng-model'? I would like to send it to the server as **person.customfields.'fieldname'** where fieldname comes from 'field in customFields'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="field in customFields">
        <label class="control-label">{{field}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.customfields[field]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="collectData()">Collect</button>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.customFields = ["Age", "Weight", "Ethnicity"];
    $scope.person = {
        customfields: {
            "Age": 0,
                "Weight": 0,
                "Ethnicity": 0
        }
    };

    $scope.collectData = function () {
        console.log($scope.person.customfields);
    }
}
```

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jqbGf/).

Updated:

For the validation, the trick is to put `<ng-form>` inside the repeater. Please [try](http://jsfiddle.net/jqbGf/2/).

Comment: I've [extended the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vorburger/jqbGf/1/) including required Field Validation, but that doesn't work.. do you have any idea how to get that working?

Assuming all fields required just for the sake of example; could be read from model, but that's irrelevant to illustrating the problem.

This is very similar to [my related problem (which has more flexible custom field 'path' in addition)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841915/angularjs-ng-model-form-driven-by-ng-repeat-over-ui-model-description-data-how-t)

Comment: @vorburger Updated. Please try.

Comment: That works - you're a genius!! ;) However, I've noticed that you have 1. switched to nested ng-form, and 2. fixed escaping in ng-show using myForm['\{\{field\}\}'].$error.required... out of curiosity I've [reverted 1. and kept 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/vorburger/jqbGf/4/) and it still works - am I missing something?  PS: I'll update my related problem.

Comment: @vorburger I am using Safari. Without doing No.1, I saw 3 alerts shown at the same time. Maybe it works on other browsers.

Comment: yeah, probably (I've tried on Chrome).  PS: As my [Fiddle #7](http://jsfiddle.net/vorburger/8CxRC/7/) illustrates, there is still an issue if input type is dynamic..

Comment: Note that wrapping each input in a `<form />` is required because AngularJS (as of version 1.1.5) does not resolve the `name` attribute against the current scope. Thus, it attaches the input to the form controller as `{{field}}`, rather than evaluating `{{ field }}` to the actual field name.

Answer (score 6):

It should be:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.customfields[field]" />
```

Comment: You need to create `$scope.person = { customfields: {} };` @Finnayra

Answer (score 4):

Any on who ends up here For `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat`

http://jsfiddle.net/sirhc/z9cGm/

the above link has good description on how to use it with examples

Comment: You should describe the solution.

Comment: Akr should indeed describe the solution, but Akr's jsfiddle example itself is absolutely fantastic and informative. Basically, bind to any array of objects which themselves contain the desired objects.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
 ng-model="person.customfields."{{field}}
Moved the double quotes

Comment: I have not tried this but I have working code for kind of similar case. Filtering based on property (name selected from dropdown)