# NgModel Inside NgRepeat with Angular Bootstrap DualListbox

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

As the title of my question implies, I am using [Angular Bootstrap DualListbox](http://frapontillo.github.io/angular-bootstrap-duallistbox/) inside an NgRepeat, but am not having any luck getting the NgModel to work properly. Let me try to mock up what I'm doing below...

ctrl.js

```
...
$scope.things = mySvc.things;
$scope.vals = mySvc.vals;
...
$scope.selectedVals = [];
$scope.doStuff = function (aThing) {
  $http.post(aUrl, { thing: aThing, val = $scope.selectedVals[0].Value })
    .success(function () {
      ...
    })
    .error(function () {
      ...
    });
};
```

tmp.html

```
...
<header ng-repeat-start="thing in things">
  {{thing.Name}}
</header>
<select
 ng-model="selectedVals"
 ng-options="val.Value for val in vals"
 multiple
 bs-duallistbox
>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn-lg" ng-click="doStuff(thing.Name)">Do Stuff</button>
<br ng-repeat-end />
```

My issue is that I cannot get `$scope.selectedVals` to pick up the selections from Angular Bootstrap DualListbox. My `$scope.doStuff` function is getting called with the `thing.Name` value passed properly, but I'm seeing an error in my console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined`. Furthermore, I can observe through console logging that `$scope.selectedVals` is, in fact, empty.

I have a more or less identical set-up working in other parts of my web app, but it does not exist in an NgRepeat, so I have to assume that is the problem. Furthermore, I've seen some other posts about issues people have had with NgModel inside NgRepeat (see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865785/angularjs-ng-model-inside-ng-repeat), [here](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/) and [here](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform)), but I can't really figure out how they relate to a solution to the particular problem that I'm having.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're going to down-vote my question, it would be helpful if you could at least provide constructive criticism about what I could do to make it more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the main problem is that you probably want to declare the `selectedVals` `Array` like this:

```
$scope.selectedVals = new Array(mySvc.things.length);
```

And use it like this in your view:

```
<header ng-repeat-start="thing in things">
  {{thing.Name}}
</header>
<select
 ngModel="selectedVals[$index]"
 ng-options="val.Value for val in vals"
 multiple
 bs-duallistbox
>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn-lg" ng-click="doStuff(thing.Name, selectedVals[$index])">Do Stuff</button>
<br ng-repeat-end />
```

And then your `doStuff` function should be something like this:

```
$scope.doStuff = function (aThing, selectedVal) {
  $http.post(aUrl, { thing: aThing, val = selectedVal)
    .success(function () {
      ...
    })
    .error(function () {
      ...
    });
};
```

Comment: @DanForbes no problem, but if I may: please consider creating a service for those $http calls

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Why do you say that?

Comment: @DanForbes it will make your code easier to reuse, test and maintain

Comment: That is a very good reason! As you can probably tell from my question, I am not really a web developer. I curate a developer service at my company, and have been charged with creating a web front-end for our consumers to use to manage their environment. I am working closely with some people in my office who are more bona fide web developers. I will touch base w/ them about modularizing the functionality of my web app. Thanks again!