# angular filter with dynamic list of attributes to search

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

my goal it to create a search box that will filter a collection either by searching all the fields, or by a specific attribute. this will be determined by a select.

[so, here's what i got](http://plnkr.co/edit/WB8C93?p=preview)

it is able to search by specific attribute, as expected, using this custom filter:
my html-

```
<tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones | filter: search ">
```

JS-

```
$scope.search = function (item){
  if (item[$scope.selectedSearchBy].indexOf($scope.query)!=-1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

note that in order to search on all of the fields, i can change my ng-repeat to be filtered as following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones | filter:query ">
```

and it will work.

However, both will not work together.

*my question is*:

***how can i create a truly generic binded dropdown and search box. that will receive the searchable attributes and take care of the filtering appropriatly?***
(preferably without using ng-show or making DOM manipulations).

would love to supply more details if needed.

Comment: make the you filters argument to be an object there you can specify what ever you want w/o affecting your filter signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How about this?](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqRp0YuFuFde2GUU5UyW?p=preview)

The *filter* filter supports the object syntax as an argument where the key is the search field and the value is the search query. For example, in your template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones | filter:{brand: query}">
```

would filter the list by *brand* according to the *query*, and

```
<tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones | filter:{'$': query}">
```

would search all the fields. So if only there's a way to do this

```
<tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones | filter:{selectedSearchBy: query}">
```

where the key of the object is set to the value of the variable `selectedSearchBy`, but [this isn't possible in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript), so I wrote a helper function to do it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones | filter:filterParam(selectedSearchBy, query)">
```