# Object.assign( ) key / value syntax

Tags: javascript

The following function updates an object with a new key and value:

```
function updateObjectWithKeyAndValue(object, key, value) {
    return Object.assign({}, object, { [key]: value })  
}
```

What I don't understand is why `key` and `value` look different. Why is `key` in brackets when `value` isn't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic keys for object literals in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript)

Comment: So the value of `key` will be used: `key = "abc";` then `{[key]: 55}` is `{"abc": 55}`.

Comment: basically the function does not update the given object. instead it returns a new object without referencing the old object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[key]` is an ES6 **computed property**. Here is a basic example:

```js
let obj = {
  [1 + 2]: 'Hello!'
};

console.log(obj[3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Computed Keys

#### **Take for example, this script using ES5:**

`function obj(x, y) { z = {}; z[x] = y; return z; }`

If you call the function `obj("weed", "sativa")` you will return `{ weed: "sativa" }`

However, you **cannot** apply more than one key simultaneously in this way, you have to do it for every key:

`function obj(w, x, y, z) { v = {}; v[w] = x; v[y] = z; return v; }`

#### **As of *ES6*, you can use computed keys.** *What does this mean?*

Instead of that, you can just do this:

`function obj(x, y) { return { [x]: y }}`

It may not look much smaller, but it means you can use multiple dynamic keys, like so:

`function obj(w, x, y, z) { return { [w]: x, [y]: z }}`

So now, doing `obj("weed", "sativa", "thc", "40%")` will return `{ weed: "sativa", thc: "40%" }`

Comment: @dfsq Thanks, Fixed It