# use property value as property key using map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to return a new array but take the property value to become property name.

```
const temp = [
  {name: 'james'},
  {name: 'ally'}
]

const new = temp.map(obj => ({
    `${obj.name}`: null
}))
```

Obviously it doesn't work this way. Any clue? https://jsfiddle.net/qg8ofom1/

Comment: `{ [obj.name]: null }`

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const temp = [
  {name: 'james'},
  {name: 'ally'}
];

const newObj = temp.map(obj => ({
    [obj.name]: null
}));

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: No real explanation - but the first correct answer - and plus+ for mending the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

couple of things are incorrect

1. `new` is a reserved word.  You can not use it to declare a variable
2. missing brackets around your `temp` array's items
3. limited in what you can use as a key:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500668/534056

try this:

```js
const temp = [
  { name: 'james' }, 
  { name: 'ally' }
]

const newObject = temp.map(obj => ({
  [obj.name]: null
}))

console.log(newObject)
```

That's ES6, so if you need to you can use bracket notation to assign properties

```js
const temp = [
  { name: 'james' },
  { name: 'ally' }
]

const new1 = temp.map(obj => {
  var x = {}
  x[obj.name] = null
  return x
})

console.log(new1)
```