# Javascript call same function multiple times with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm new in stack, so be patient with me, please.
I have a simple function with parameters and I'm using Jquery:

```
function AnimateValues(a, b, c, d){
  return $(a).stop().animate({b : c}, d);
}
```

now, I'd like to call it when needed eg:

```
AnimateValues('#div1', 'opacity', 1, 500);
AnimateValues('#div2', 'opacity', 0, 500);
AnimateValues('#div3', 'top', 20, 500);
...
```

but it seems only the last one is executed.
Helps will be appreciate.

Comment: Are you calling the function in a loop, or actually three times in a row as shown above

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code from where you are calling the function.

Comment: `only the last one is executed` does not make sense, because your code should not work for any of them in the way you expect, because `{b : c}` would not use the value of the parameter `b` as key for the object but the name `b` itself. So it would never animate `top` or `opactiy`.

Comment: I supposed to use a loop but no, I need to call it as shown 'cause I don't know in advance how many times I need to call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic keys for object literals in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `b` parameter in `[]` otherwise its just string key.

```js
function AnimateValues(a, b, c, d){
  return $(a).stop().animate({[b] : c}, d);
}

AnimateValues('#div1', 'opacity', 1, 500);
AnimateValues('#div2', 'opacity', 0, 500);
AnimateValues('#div3', 'top', 20, 500);
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div1</div>
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
<div id="div3">Div3</div>
```

Comment: Another time, please use the dup-hammer granted by having a gold badge in JavaScript to *close* duplicate question instead of providing answers to them.

Answer (score -1):

This is not really an answer to your question because, `only the last one is executed` does not make sense.

Your code should not work for any of them in the way you expect, because `{b : c}` would not use the value of the parameter `b` as key for the object but the name `b` itself. So it would never animate `top` or `opactiy`

If you can use ES6 features then you could write `[b]` instead of `b` which would use the value ob `b` as key.

```
function AnimateValues(a, b, c, d){
  return $(a).stop().animate({[b] : c}, d);
}
```

Or

```
function AnimateValues(a, b, c, d){
  var params = {};
  params[b] = c;
  return $(a).stop().animate(params, d);
}
```

But as I said, this would not explain your `only the last one is executed`.