# What is this in javascript and what is it's point?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have seen this in javascript but have no idea what it does. can someone explain? and before you say "google it". I have tried and I cannot see any results for it

```
return {
    [API]: {
        data: { someData },
        anotherKey: true,
}
```

I know `API` is a string from the code I'm looking at but I'm not sure what this is doing

I'm used to just seeing an object returned like this.

```
return {
   key: value
}
```

can someone please enlighten me? happy to read docs/videos etc. just honestly not sure what to google to find them

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript Possibly a duplicate? Particularly the *"Computed property names"* answers.

Comment: Specifically, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38774377/1822698

Comment: @KevinB I'm sure there's a dup but that one looks a little old; this question is specifically about computed property names in an object initializer.

Comment: Agreed, why i'm hesitant to hammer it

Comment: @slider ah good, cool

Comment: They are computed property names https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: don't hammer me folks, I have been given my answer now. the tech world moves forward

Comment: I had no idea this existed. Thanks for asking the question and everyone else for answering it.

Comment: @TheDecimator Sorry that was just SO lingo, hammer means close as duplicate. That makes this post essentially a sign post to another Q&A pair that already has a good answer to this question. It's referred to as a "hammer" when it is done by someone with a gold tag badge, because it can be done with a single vote by such users. Not a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

These are known as [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). Hopefully this example illustrates it's mechnanism and usefulness

```js
let pet = 'cat';
let person1 = {name: "Dave", [pet]: "Muffin"};

pet = 'dog';
let person2 = {name: "Mary", [pet]: "Fido"};


console.log(person1,person2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If API is a string, let's say `"apiObject"` then you have

```
return 
    {
    apiObject: {
        data: { someData },
        anotherKey: true,
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the [API] return format is for an "object", the second is simply a return "value". I may be wrong, that's just my first guess.