# Using var in js for cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this js code:

```
var grade_type = document.getElementById("grade_type").value;

gradesRef.set({
          grade_type: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(grade)
        });
```

But in my cloud firestore the field is going to be named with: 'grade_type'. But I want to name the field like the **value of grade_type**.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gradesRef.set({
      [grade_type]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(grade)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not firebase related, you are just looking for a way to write an object literal with variable key in NodeJS. There are plenty of articles explaining that, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500573/4038448).

@MrAleister's answer seems to be the easiest one {[variable_name]: value}

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of a property with the value of a variable in JavaScript like this:

```
const fields = {}
fields[grade_type] = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(grade)
```

Then pass the object to Firestore:

```
gradesRef.set(fields)
```