# Use variable outside the object to be the object variable

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < lootbox.length; i++) {
  const { type } = lootbox[i]
  const query = type + "_lootbox.hunt";

  await lb.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userID: message.author.id },
    { $inc: { query: 1 } }
  );
}
```

the code reads the `query` as its own variable instead of the `type + "_lootbox.hunt"`, is there a way to use that query inside the `$inc`? because I want to automate it using the loop

AKA. dynamic object key

Comment: How about `query:  query` instead of hard-coding `1`? Is that actually what you're asking?

Comment: err I want to increment it by 1, with the `type + "_lootbox.hunt"`

Comment: Well your code as posted makes no attempt to do anything of that sort.

Comment: Your title isn't very clear, what *variable outside the object*? Which *object*? To be *the object variable*, which object variable? See where im going with this

Comment: sorry my english isnt good, I mean to access that `query` inside the `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript I think this answers my questions thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to create an object on the fly, but you can not set a key like that dynamically.

To achieve that you need to prepare this object prior to use.

And, in such a case your code would be something like this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < lootbox.length; i++) {
  const { type } = lootbox[i]
  const query = type + "_lootbox.hunt";
  const tempObject = {}; // Creating an empty Object
  tempObject[query] = 1; // Dynamic key usage
  await lb.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userID: message.author.id },
    { $inc: tempObject } // Using the tempObject
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you want is this:
in each iteration `query` becomes `type + "_lootbox.hunt"`, for example `page1_lootbox.hunt`. And what you want to get is `{ $inc: { "page1_lootbox.hunt": 1 }}`. If so, a simple solution will be

```
{ $inc: { [query]: 1 } }    // { $inc: { "page1_lootbox.hunt": 1 } }
```

Let me know if you want something different.