# How to use get the value from the nth child key of the object by using variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question is similar to this: [How do I interpolate a variable as a key in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640988/how-do-i-interpolate-a-variable-as-a-key-in-a-javascript-object)

However, I have a difficult on using variables on nth keys:

I had a object, which is:

```
var object = {};
object.foo = "foo";
object.foo.bar = "bar";
object.foo.bar.alice = "alice";
object.foo.bar.alice.bob = "bob";
```

I am able to get the value (`foo`) for `object.foo` by using the variable `object["foo"]`

But I cannot find out a way to access to `object.foo.bar` value.

I tried `object["foo"]["bar"]`, but it does not work.

In addition to my question, how can I get the value for

```
object.foo.bar.alice
object.foo.bar.alice.bob
```

By using variable as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need an object for foo, because foo is a [primitive type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

```
var object = {};
object.foo = "foo";
object.foo.bar = "bar"; // does not work!
```

This works

```
var object = {};
object.foo = {};
object.foo.bar = "bar"; // work!
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
var object = {};
object.foo = "foo";
```

You define the property as `string` and it won't store the keys since it is **a string literal** **not a string object**.

you need to try

```
var object = {};
object.foo = new String("foo");
```

Now it can store more properties in `object.foo`.

```js
var object = {};
object.foo = new String( "foo" );
object.foo.bar = new String( "bar" );
object.foo.bar.alice = new String( "alice" );
object.foo.bar.alice.bob = new String( "bob" );

console.log( object );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, how can I access for the the value for the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` to output `foo` ?. image: http://i.imgur.com/ZYhUflM.png

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign as a object {key:value,key:value}

```
object.foo = {0:"foo",bar:{}};
object.foo.bar = {0:"bar",alice:{}};
object.foo.bar.alice = {0:"alice",bob:{}};
object.foo.bar.alice.bob = "bob";
console.log(object.foo.bar.alice);
console.log(object.foo.bar.alice.bob);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a simple function to get the nested objects and their keys dynamically. Such as the following. A similar approach would be sufficient for the set version as well.

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

var arr = [{fox: [{turn:[857, 432]}]}, {sax: [{pana:[777, 987]}]}, {ton: [{joni:[123, 567]}]}, {piu: [{burn:[666, 37]}]}, {sia: [{foxy:[404, 696]}]}],
  myObj = {foo: {bar: {alice: {bob: "bob"}}}};

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr.getNestedValue(3,"piu",0,"burn",1),null,2) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr.getNestedValue(3,"piu",0,"burn"),null,2) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(myObj.getNestedValue("foo","bar","alice","bob"),null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Keep in mind that you can set your nested properties in an array in the order of appearance and then call like `myDeeplyNestedObj.getNestedValue(...propsArray)`