# Node Sequalize Query "where" key interpoloation

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

User table has a column called "name" and `req.body.key = name`. 
I don't want to write `name = req.body.value`. 
How do i somehow interpolate req.body.key? 
`"{req.body.key}"` doesn't work and console throws `User.{req.body.key} does not exist`.

```
function(req, res, next) {
    User.findAll({
        where: {
            //Question HERE
            req.body.key : req.body.value           
        }
    }).then(...).catch(...)
}
```

Comment: this solves it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640988/how-do-i-interpolate-a-variable-as-a-key-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: What about the answer below? It has the advantage of showing ES6 too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function(req, res, next) {
    var whereClause = {};
    whereClause[req.body.key] = req.body.value;
    extend(whereClause, req.body);
    User.findAll({
        where: whereClause
    }).then(...).catch(...)
}
```

In [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) (node > 5-6 I don't remember) you can also:

```
function(req, res, next) {
    extend(whereClause, req.body);
    User.findAll({
        [req.body.key]: eq.body.value
    }).then(...).catch(...)
}
```